# problem with DATETIME, calculation of time between two dates c#

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

Hellou everybody
I have two datepicker when customer´s  choose date from and to date .
Everything goes to me, the computer gives me time and also shows the label, the problem is that the datepicker does not add a day. I have the day stored in the MS access database where it also does not add days.
I want that when a customer gives a date from 1.5.2020 to 1.6.2020 (which he chooses from a datepicker (or any day)), he will count down the day every day.
How to do it ?

Thank´s many for answer

Comment: `dateTimePicker1.Value` and `dateTimePicker2.Value` should already be of type `DateTime`. If you want the difference then subtract the smaller from the larger `var difference = dateTimePicker2.Value.Subtract(dateTimePicker1.Value);`. Then you can display that how you see fit.

Comment: I also think you are using a timer (timer2_Tick) but there is no explanation on why that is.

Comment: I need 1 day to count down every day until the end, I thought the timer would be a good choice, I'm just a beginner

Comment: A timer is useful if you want an action to occur repetitively and at a specific frequency *or* if you want to schedule an action for the future. It is not useful for an atomic operation like calculating the difference between 2 dates.